# Power Factor Circuit

Tags: power, grounding, power-factor-correction

I am currently working on an energy meter that requires to know the Power Factor in order to get the Actual Power in the circuit.

The circuit diagram attached [image: Power Factor Circuit]shows my circuit diagram and it is working fine (when simulated)

But I now want to build the physical circuit, and I'm confused if all the grounds in the circuit should be connected together or not.
Is it safe to connect all together?

Any insight shall be appreciated

Comment: That is what the ground symbol means. But you tell me whether it's safe.

Comment: Especially tell me whether it's safe when the plug is plugged in backwards.

Comment: Is this circuit to measure the angle between V and I zero-cross?

Comment: *I am currently working on an energy meter that requires to know the Power Factor in order to get the Actual Power in the circuit* - any reason why you are trying to calculate power using this problematic and inaccurate method that nobody ever uses?

Comment: It doesn't make sens to use all these logic gates and comparators without rectified current. I don;t see any bridge rectifier in your circuit. + It doesn't make sens to connect the ground to one wire of the AC source (if your source is DC then please change the symbol). If the ground is connected to AC, all the DC components will be destroyed immediately.